# subdivision surface display

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

when enable my subdivision surface looks like that:
 [image]

I have seen a video with this display for the subdivision surface on edit mode (the edges are no longer straight and we don't see them with transparency because they fit the shape of the mesh with subsurf) How can I get this type of display ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 'adjust edit cage' button on the modifier panel.

[image]