# "Adjust edit cage to modifier result " what does this do (with Mirror Modifier)?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I've been following a tut in Modelling and all of a sudden the instructor turns on this feature  "Adjust edit cage to modifier result " without explaining what it does. The instructor couldn't give me a proper answer. So far didn't find an answer online which explains this feature clearly.

[image]

Comment: Have a look https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145158/subdivision-surface-display/145159#145159 It displays the mesh as result mesh after the modifier is calculated.

Comment: It seems to be doing something opposite to what Ctrl + R does ?

Comment: No, it is just a view of the mesh. It is literally "adjusting edit cage to modifier result". Edit cage is the mesh as it is inside the object. With this option, these vertices (edit cage) are viewed at the position they will be after the modifier is calculated.

Answer (score 3):

In this example I have a plane with 4 faces and a subdivision surface modifier of x 2.

The first image shows the vertex position on the mesh (edit cage off)

The second image shows the same vertex but the position is where it sits as if the subdivision surface modifier had been applied (edit cage on).

[image]

[image]

With a mirror modifier applied make sure you have the stacking order correct:

This shows the mirror modifier below the subdivision surface modifier

[image]

This one show the other way around

[image]

As you can see the subdivision surface should be below the mirror modifier

One final point. If you have edit cage on then selecting the vertex the cursor will still remain on the mesh vertex and not on the adjusted subsurface vertex position.

[image]

Comment: You mean the Subdivision Surface ? Thanks for simplifying it. It works differently with mirror modifier.

Comment: Original answer edited with mirror modifier added

Answer (score 0):

WRT to Mirror modifier in 2.8 beta

In modelling I was using this feature with respect to the "MIRROR" modifier. Turning on "adjust edit cage to modifier result" basically Makes vertices and edges appear on the other side(instead of a plane surface) and also turns on the Selected part on the Mirroring side as well . Eg: If you select a vertex on the right side of the Symmetry, this feature will also highlight the Vertex on the Mirroring side.